# Writing summaries in Tensorflow leads to extra evaluation of graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, reproducible-research, tensorflow-slim

Writing summaries using Tensorflow Supervisor re-evaluates the graph which can have undesired consequences.

One such consequence is changing the random state and in turn affecting reproducibility. I have written a small example to demonstrate this affect.

```
import tensorflow as tf
N = 5
SEED = 123
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.set_random_seed(SEED)
    a = tf.random_uniform([1])
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        for i in range(N):
            print(sess.run([a]))
# result: [0.31000066],[0.36025488],[0.9802418],[0.94300663],[0.03890145]

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.set_random_seed(SEED)
    a = tf.random_uniform([1])
    summary = tf.summary.scalar(name='a', tensor=a[0])
    sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir="./tmp", summary_op=summary,
                             save_summaries_secs=0.1)
    with sv.managed_session() as sess:
        for _ in range(N):
            print(sess.run(a))
# result of first run: [0.9802418],[0.94300663],[0.03890145],[0.2266953],[0.42769837]
# result of second run:[0.36025488],[0.9802418],[0.94300663],[0.03890145],[0.2266953]
```

In the example above, I define two graphs both with the same graph-level random seed. In the second graph, I write summaries using tf.train.Supervisor. Then I generate N random numbers by evaluating each graph N times. The graph with the summary writer “skips” some random numbers; so depending on when the summaries are written in relation to the global step, you get randomly different results.

Another example where this affect has undesired consequences is when you use batching with Tensorflow record reader and writing summaries with the Supervisor leads to consumption of an extra batch of data per summary writing due to the extra graph evaluation.

This also affects the behavior of all tools that depend on the Supervisor, such as Tensorflow-slim.

Is there a conventional way to communicate to the Supervisor to collect ops and their respective summaries in the same graph evaluation?
I suppose one could work around this by defining dependencies between ops and their summaries, and passing `summary_op=None`.

Answer (score 0):

The situation seems to have been addressed in tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession which deprecates the Supervisor:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.set_random_seed(SEED)
    a = tf.random_uniform([1])
    summary = tf.summary.scalar(name='a', tensor=a[0])
    step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step')
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(checkpoint_dir="./tmp2",
                                           save_summaries_steps=1) as sess:
        for _ in range(N):
            print(sess.run([a]))
# result: [0.31000066],[0.36025488],[0.9802418],[0.94300663],[0.03890145]
```